# Vertical alignment with img and navlink/text with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, anchor, vertical-alignment

https://codepen.io/bencasalino/pen/GRJNGJe

```
<li class="navbar-link">
  <a href="#">
    <img class ="img" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="test"> CENTER THIS LINK VERTICALLY IN THE MIDDLE OF THE CAT PIC  </a>
</li>
```

I'm trying to align the link vertically with the image. My thought was to use flexbox but I wrapped the text in a span tag so flexbox recognizes it as a child element. Not sure if the structure of the HTML is the issue or that using flexbox is not the answer.

Comment: are you looking for : `img {vertical-align:middle;}` or do you want the text on top of the image ?

Comment: Do you want the text to appear underneath the image, or actually on top of the image?

Comment: there's a few possibilities : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOpLKEa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sice your image and nav link are inside the anchor tag, you can add style to anchor. Check the snippet

```
a{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```css
li{
  list-style:none
}
a{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<li class="navbar-link">
  <a href="#">
    <img class ="img" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="test"> CENTER THIS LINK VERTICALLY IN THE MIDDLE OF THE CAT PIC  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: I think the flex-direction was throwing me off, this is a simple answer, thank you for the snippet!